# Pasar un txt a un arreglo en JAVA

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda. Tengo la siguiente información en un fichero de texto *.txt*

```
Isabel Garcia,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  
Luis Fernando,10,09,09,09,09,09,09  
Isabel Flores,10,09,09,09,09,09,09
```

¿Cuál sería el código para leer el txt que está guardado en determinada ruta y convertirlo a un arreglo bidimensional en JAVA?

Hasta ahora sólo tengo este código con WHILE pero no lo guarda en un array, sólo lo lee y lo muestra:

```
File calificaciones; 
FileReader leerArchivo;
leerArchivo = new FileReader("c:/calificaciones.txt"); 
BufferedReader textoArchivo = new BufferedReader(leerArchivo); 
while (cadena!=null) {
    cadena= textoArchivo.readLine();
    if (cadena!=null) {
        System.out.println(cadena);
   }
}
textoArchivo.close();
leerArchivo.close();
```

Necesito el código para guardar el nombre en una posición, por ejemplo [0][0], la primera calificación en la [0][1] y así sucesivamente. Separe los datos por ",".

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que utilizando de apoyo una lista y el método `split` puedes manipular la información del archivo de la manera que necesitas.

```
ArrayList<String[]> AUX = new ArrayList<>();
int lineas = 0;//Para numero de filas de la matriz
int cols = 0;//Para numero de columnas de la matriz

File calificaciones; 
FileReader leerArchivo;
leerArchivo = new FileReader("c:/calificaciones.txt"); 
BufferedReader textoArchivo = new BufferedReader(leerArchivo);

//Quiza no sea la manera mas optima de hacer la lectura del archivo... 
while (cadena!=null) {
  cadena= textoArchivo.readLine();
  if (cadena!=null) {
    //System.out.println(cadena);
    AUX.add(cadena.split(","));//Almacena cada array (lineas del archivo) en la lista
    lineas++;
  }
}

if(AUX.size()>0) {
  System.out.printf("Archivo a Matriz:%n");
  cols = AUX.get(0).length;
  info = new String[lineas][cols];

  for(int i=0; i<lineas; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      //Captura el elemento (array) de la lista y [j] trae el dato en esa posición del arreglo.
      info[i][j] = AUX.get(i)[j];
      System.out.print(info[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
} else {
  System.printf("No hay datos%n");
}

textoArchivo.close();
leerArchivo.close();
```

De ese modo resulta la matriz con los datos debidamente tabulados.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su valiosa ayuda. Todas las respuestas me resultaron muy útiles y por fin, pude resolver el problema. Nuevamente gracias por compartir su conocimiento y fomentar la educación.

Answer (score 2):

Esto creo que te ayuda.

Crea un txt en tu PC con la dirección que aparece dentro del código o donde tu gustes. Pero ten presente que debes modificar esa dirección en java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File archivo = null;
    FileReader Fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        archivo = new File("C:/TIENDA/MATRIZ.txt"); // Ruta desde donde se lee el txt
        Fr = new FileReader(archivo.toString());
        br = new BufferedReader(Fr);
        String linea;
        String delimiter = ","; //Separador dentro del txt. Cuando crees tu archivo de texto en la maquina separa los números por comas. No los pongas en linea recta, pon uno sobre otro

        String matriz[][] = new String[2][2]; // Te leera una matriz de 2*2

        int numlinea=0;

        while (((linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {

            String a[]=linea.split(delimiter);

            for (int l = 0; l < a.length; l++) {
                matriz[numlinea][l] = a[l];
            }
            numlinea++;
        }
         System.out.println("MATRIZ");
         System.out.println("------");
           for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length; filas++) {
                for (int colum = 0; colum < matriz[filas].length; colum++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[filas][colum]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();   
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: por favor explícalo, pues no es solo colocar código y ya

Comment: Excelente, esta adaptable para cualquier instancia de trabajo con parametros externos, lo que nos permite flexibilizar los datos a procesar, Gracias por su aporte

Answer (score 0):

```
package arrays;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GuardarArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTest();
    }

    public static void runTest() {
        String filePath = "c:/calificaciones.txt";
        FileReader leerArchivo;
        BufferedReader textoArchivo;
        List content;
        try {
            leerArchivo  = new FileReader(new File(filePath));
            textoArchivo = new BufferedReader(leerArchivo);

            content = getContent(textoArchivo);
            try {
                textoArchivo.close();
                leerArchivo.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error -> " + ex);
            }

            // Show the results
            if (content != null) {
                showResults(content);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error -> " + ex);
        }
    }

    private static List getContent(BufferedReader bufReader) {
        List content = new ArrayList();
        String lineContent = "";
        int lineNumber     = 0;
        while (lineContent != null) {

            try {
                lineContent = bufReader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(
                   "Error reading line: " + lineNumber + " -> " + ex);
            }
            if (lineContent != null && ! lineContent.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Line readed: " + lineContent);

                String[] lineElements = lineContent.split(",");
                content.add(lineElements);
            }

            lineNumber++;
        }

        return content;
    }

    private static void showResults(List content) {
        System.out.println("Readed contents .................................");

        for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
            String[] lineElements = (String[]) content.get(i);
            for (String lineElement : lineElements) {
                System.out.print(lineElement + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

He guardado el resultado en una lista a partir del método `getContent()` al que le paso la instancia de *BufferedReader*. En el ejemplo muestro su contenido con el método: `showResults()`.

Una vez que puedes leer el fichero fila a fila, como estas tienen un formato determinado (datos separados por comas), se puede obtener un array de strings con los datos de cada fila, obteniendo sus elementos a partir del separador (,):

```
String[] lineElements = lineContent.split(",");
```

Como en teoría no se sabe que número de filas tiene el archivo, guarda cada uno de los arrays que se obtienen anteriormente en una lista:

```
content.add(lineElements);
```

La lista será devuelta al finalizar la lectura del fichero.

Answer (score 0):

El primer algoritmo es para leer archivos de texto plano en la ubicación de tu disco local

```
public Stream<String> leerAchivoLocal(String ruta) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(ruta), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
       if(lineas != null) lineas.close();
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

El segundo algoritmo una vez leído todo el documento puedes hacer la conversión

```
public String[][] texto2arreglo(Stream<String> archivo){
    List<String> textos = archivo.collect(Collectors.toList());

    int filas = textos.size();
    int columnas = textos.get(0).split(",").length;

    String arreglo[][] = new String[filas][columnas];

    IntStream.range(0, filas).forEach(y -> {
        String linea = textos.get(y);
        IntStream.range(0, columnas).forEach(x -> {
            arreglo[y][x] = linea.split(",")[x];
        });
    });

   return arreglo;
}
```